# Questions about security of platform

Tags: discussion

Are questions about the security of PaaS solutions (Outsystems in this case) allowed on security.stackexchange? It is a little bit a opinion based question, but on the other hand it is also an experience based question. The questions would be something like:

- How did you experience the security of Outsystems?
- How easy was it for a developer to just circumvent Security measures in the platform?
- How to make sure secure applications are build with this platform? In terms of technical measures but also procedures.

Thanks for your replies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The security of platform as a Service (PaaS) is definitely on topic here, however your questions are not.

Your first two are entirely opinion which makes them off topic.

The final one could be on topic if structured as "how to secure PaaS applications" or "what key security elements are required in PaaS" but at the end of the day, all these "... as a service" options are mostly the same as ordinary solutions, they just reside somewhere else on a server someone else owns and controls, so you would use the same controls as normal, **plus** controls to protect you and your data from that 3rd party.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Going further on the third question then: Is it on topic to talk about how to procedurally and contractmanagemently take it up with the service providers? Or is this forum only for technological questions? Also would a question about the pitfalls in security of a specific PaaS be on topic or not?

Comment: Hmmm - it could vary. In terms of how to talk to a provider, I don't think that would be on topic here as it would be different for every one. We do have a lot of questions on pitfalls of specific products - have a browse around to see which one's work and which don't

Comment: The site is not just for tech questions, it is also for procedural or behavioural etc. But it is only for infosec questions (see [ask] and our [about] page)

Comment: I was thinking the 2nd question was less opinion, more "too broad" (as it is rather unspecific). Still effectively the same, though :-)

Comment: Oh - yep, that works too @avid